# create a array of kendo multi-select selected id

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

i am try to create a array of selected id using kendo multi select.

here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9WfGA/24/)
this is kendo script:-

```
$("#multiselect").kendoMultiSelect({
  dataSource: [
    { id: 1, name: "Apples" },
    { id: 2, name: "Oranges" }
  ],
  dataTextField: "name",
  dataValueField: "id",
    select:onSelect
});
```

kendo select function:-

```
function onSelect(e){
    var dataItem = this.dataSource.view()[e.item.index()];
    onchng(dataItem.id);
}
```

create a array:-

```
function onchng(id){
var checkarr = [];
    checkarr.push(id);
    console.log(checkarr);
}
```

here is output is `[1] [2]` 
but i want it `['1','2']`
is it possible??
thanks

Answer (score 0):

When your select event fired, **'checkarr'** redefined again and again. Your problem is that. If you want values in one array, you must use a button to take values together, then push them to array in single function. Or you can use session or something like that

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it from the Controller. Note I'm doing Request.Form, that's because for whatever reason MVC Model and Kendo UI wouldn't work together when using MultiComplete. But this will put them in an array, and this is fired off a button click like the other answer suggested.

```
 string[] advertisers = Request.Form["Name"].ToString().Split(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is a much easier approach and with less side effects...

Bind `change` event instead of `select`. Why? Two reasons:

1. `select` is fired just before the element is added to the list of values so you cannot get current list and you need to add the value being selected to the values already selected.
2. `select` is not fired when you remove the selection of an option.

The code using `change` would be as simple as:

```
var multi = $("#multiselect").kendoMultiSelect({
    dataSource: [
        { id: 1, name: "Apples" },
        { id: 2, name: "Oranges" }
    ],
    dataTextField: "name",
    dataValueField: "id",
    change : onSelect
}).data("kendoMultiSelect");

function onSelect(){
    console.log("here", multi.value());
}
```

Just need to use `value` method from your `multiselect`.

Your Fiddle modified in here : http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/datasource#events-change

NOTE: `change` event belongs to `DataSource` if you need to see the documentation, check it [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/datasource#events-change)